# Update a Div Automatically with Jquery When New Record Added in MySql Database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm making a Social networking website for my friends. i wanted to know how i would Update a Div containing few inserted records of the database, when a new record is added in the database. In short you must have seen the live notifications of facebook, which fade in when someone does something . this all happens without the refreshing of the whole live notification div. only the new notification is prepend to the div.

I would like to do this using jquery and AJAX as i have good knowledge about them. and PHP as the server side language.

Thank you in Advance.

P.S : I have searched many websites for the solution, but couldnt find it anywhere. i Even tried going through facebook's Source code but couldnt find it there too ! I hope someone helps me here ! ****crossed fingers****

Comment: You're looking for something like http://dailyjs.com/2010/08/17/polling/ I think.

Comment: There’s a [good Wikipedia page on this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet%5F%28programming%29).

Comment: no! i just want a simple jquery div refresh when new record added to database . and refresh should be done only once .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically it goes something like this:

Create a javascript function on your page that makes an ajax call (with jquery or native xhr or what not)  to a php page. The php page keeps track of "new stuff" and returns it when called. The js function, when receiving data, add new tags (divs or whatever) to the notification bar. The function is called every once in a while with javascript's `setTimeout` function.

If some of these steps are confusing to you please ask a more specific question.

Comment: I understood your answer . If i make a php file. then how do i send a query which selects only the newly added items in the database ?

Comment: Well, if you know what determines a "newly added" item, all you have to do is select them and return them as JSON. If, to determine what is new, you need to know when the client last asked for an item, you should send a timestamp with your request to the php page. The php page would then perform a query like `select * from something where added > ?`, and then format the result as JSON.

Comment: yea that seems to be more effective. will try that right now :) thanks :)

Comment: but then i would have to keep a time field for every insert in the database ?

Comment: @SyedSamirUddin well, not necesarily... you could keep an id (you probably already have one) and then just send the latest id to the client. You php page could then do a `select * from something where id > ?`. However, having an `added` timestamp for each row probably wouldn't be that bad of an idea... Remember that, to keep track of this between user visits, you need a `lasttimeusersawsomething` or `idoflastthingusersaw`.

Comment: yes yes i have the id option ! i would rather do that ! ;-) thanks alot !

Comment: U made my day ! it worked perfectly fine ! THANKS ALOTTTTT !!! (y). 

P.S : if i will be having any further problems , i hope u wont mind if i disturb u :P

Comment: I'm happy to help. Disturb all you want, I'll always answer if I have time ;-)

Answer (score 5):

You can either use Ajax Push to send a notification that the post is updated, or you can make it pull-driven.  The latter would probably be easier for you if you already know jquery and Ajax with PHP.

Periodically check for new records on an interval (using `setInterval`, for example) and if you find them, load them to the DOM and fade them in.  The interval doesn't have to be very small and waste resources .. maybe something as long as every 30 seconds will do.

```
setInterval('checkForUpdates', 30000);
var lastTime = (new Date()).getTime();
function checkForUpdates() {
   $.get('/php-page-that-checks-for-updates.php?timestamp=' . lastTime
      , function (results) {
         if (results) { /* fade into dom */ }
      }
   );
   lastTime = (new Date()).getTime();
}
```

PHP page:

```
$timestamp = $_REQUEST['timestamp'];
$results = query('SELECT post FROM posts WHERE postTime > "$timestamp"');
echo fetch($results);
```

As others suggested, you can also mark posts as "read" and use that as an indicator instead of the timestamp, which will also solve a time zone problem with my example.  I wouldn't want to add an extra column just to do this, but if you already have one for some other reason it'd be a good idea.

EDIT: This is a pretty old answer, but if you can still do it I would use WebSockets instead of any kind of ajax long polling.  I don't think that PHP is a great language (I would suggest using socket.io with Node.js), but it is possible.

Comment: i have used the 'read' method but as i said before. until and unless someone clicks on it, it will keep refreshing. to be more precise. the home page of facebook fades in the new status of somebody without refreshing the page. and new comments are displayed without refreshing the page.

Comment: i understand :) but it will keep refreshing the respective div every 30 seconds with the notifications whose 'read' is '0' :) . any ways i got the point. i will try it :) thank u :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's `$.getJSON()` method to access a PHP page. This PHP page would grab all unread notifications (you could add a column in your notifications table called "read" and set it to `0` for unread and `1` for unread) and return them as a JSON feed.

Parse the JSON and make each one a div that shows up on the page. Then wrap this all in a `setInterval()` and run it every millisecond (or half a second, or quarter of a second, it's up to you).

Also, to mark them as read, set up a click event on these `div`s that you created from the JSON notification feed. On click, it will contact another PHP page (you can use `$.post` or `$.get`) which will receive the `id` of the notification, for example, and change the `read` column to 1.

Comment: but then until and unless someone clicks on them . that php file would be refreshing those notifications on every refresh.

Comment: Exactly. That means they're unread. Of course it could be modified to only do it once...you could add yet another column called "displayed"that is set to 1 the first time it is retrieved from the database.