# PHP/AJAX Update the page on mysql updates

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I need a script that can check if a new row is inserted, and then return back to the main page, to load another page with ajax.

Right now I do it every x secs, which is not optional in this case:

```
 function refresh()
 {
      $("#conent").load("ajax.php");
  }

  setInterval('refresh()', 3000);
```

So how do i make the following: Whenever the mysql database is updated, it need to check it and return and load `$("#conent").load("ajax.php");`

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: I think you need to do some research on _PHP Push Notification_

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8364541/update-a-div-automatically-with-jquery-when-new-record-added-in-mysql-database

Comment: http://blog.codebusters.pl/en/auto-refresh-content-after-changes-in-database-ajax/